# Set scrollbar opacity while dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a website that has this feature working:

```
http://www.annexcore.com/
```

When you click on their scrollbar is changes the opacity of it so it's darker.  This is easy to replicate by using `:hover` in my CSS file.

But, when you continue dragging and move the mouse to the left so it isn't hovering anymore, the opacity stays dark as long as you're still dragging it.  They are using nicescroll just like I am but I can't figure out how to make it so that the opacity stay dark while dragging (without users being forced to hover over the scrollbar).

Can anyone see what they are doing to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems they're relying on window.onscroll as well as on hover - try to start scrolling an hold for a while - scrollbar will become transparent again. I think this should do the trick

```
var timer, el = $('scrollbar'), scrollInProgress = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!scrollInProgress) {
        scrollInProgress = true;
        el.addClass('scrolling');
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        el.removeClass('scrolling');
        scrollInProgress = false;
    }, 200);
});
```